# How to move to a room with 'no registration'

Tags: resident-permit

I need some advice about registration. I am currently registered in the Netherlands but want to move to a room that I cannot get registration for. If I were to leave the Netherlands for a few days, then re-enter, does this mean that I don't need registration as I will have been here less than 4 months?
I arrived 21st August 2017 and will leave around January.

Comment: why can't you register at the room? usually there's a reason, like the owner is violating the terms of their lease or something fishy. see https://community.justlanded.com/en/Netherlands/forum/I-have-rented-a-flat  like all registrations, you should ask in your city for further advice